# Javascript Fetch - Interpret header as UTF-8?

Tags: javascript, http, fetch-api

I need to fetch a UTF-8 string from a header in a React Native application like so:

```
fetch('https://www.example.com', {
  method: 'HEAD',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
  }
}).then((res) => {
  console.log(res.headers.get('example-header'))
}
```

However, I have some german characters such as `ü` being logged as `Ã¼`.

According to [this article](https://php-de.github.io/jumpto/utf-8/), the `ü` is being interpreted as `ISO 8859-1 (Latin-1)`.

Looking at the response headers, I clearly see `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`

Is there a way to ensure the header is properly decoded as UTF-8?

Is it even possible?

It works in the Firefox console.

Comment: Try this: `response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");`

Comment: Encode it as JSON or base 64 or any other ASCII-safe encoding. There's no plain non-ASCII in HTTP headers.

Comment: @PatricNox unfortunately that doesn't work.

Comment: @deceze I was worried about that but was confused as this works in the Firefox console, but not in a React Native application - have edited to clarify.